# Active Directory account is being locked while browsing Stack Overflow with Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome

I am a network administrator, and I'm encountering a strange problem with some users that are browsing Stack Overflow.

When some of my users are browsing Stack Overflow from Chrome, their Active Directory account gets locked out.

I have got some of them to try use other browsers and this doesn't lock them out.

Has anyone seen this before, and is there perhaps a workaround? Is this an unlikely coincidence?

Comment: AD = active directory?

Comment: This is a bit unclear, but it seems like you have an actual question. What's the problem you're facing, and what are you trying to address? What's your current configuration, including all details which could be remotely relevant? Additionally, what is an "AD" in this context? Please feel free to edit relevant details into this question.

Comment: "Your users"? What does it mean? What AD accounts? What OpenID provider are they using? What exactly is getting "locked out"?

Comment: Yes AD = Active Directory, Users = Im the IT guy and developers use StackOverflow. I have just been having a play about on stackoverflow and it locked me out when i create this post. Others have said its when they logout from the site.

Comment: OK, I did my best to make this into a proper question. That's obviously not a bug on Stack Overflow side. **I will ask again: what is your OpenID provider? How exactly you log into Stack Overflow?**

Comment: Thanks im a first time poster here, Im not sure why it would lock it out but thought id ask on here because im a bit lost why its doing this. It seems if they are using any method, im using google.

Comment: Well, you should really ask your network admin. Does your Active Directory server and Google accounts somehow synchronized or tied together? This might explain whose weird isssues.

Comment: Maybe some intrusion detection system "recognizes" the websockets connects to SO as attacks and locks the "offending" account? (as far as I know only logged-in users use websockets, so that would fit with the "logging in locks me out") If so, the problem is definitely somewhere in your system.

Comment: @JoachimSauer but Firefox also support web sockets and it doesn't happen when they're logged in using Firefox.

Comment: I am the network admin. I have been trying to track down why this has been happening for some time now, At first we thought it was our web proxy that was causing the lockouts ( Sophos UTM ) but they have been through the setup and the authentication request is coming from the users machine not the webproxy.

Comment: Does anything in your policy perhaps trigger on third-party cookies being set? I reopened this, just in case it's not a strange coincidence. I wouldn't immediately suspect websockets, or you'd see this much more frequently.

Comment: Thanks Tim, im not sure. We haven't got anything specifically in place to do with third party cookies. Would disabling them on my browser show if this is the issue ?

Comment: Ben, please use `@` when replying to comments e.g. @Tim will notify Tim Post there is a new comment.

Comment: @shawizdoward Cheers didnt realise how it works here

Comment: @Ben success! As Tim appears to be away my advice is "try and see", no harm in temporarily disabling cookies to see if it solve the issue.

Comment: @shawizdoward I have blocked third party cookies and it seems to have stopped the lockouts.

Comment: Interesting. Wish I had more knowledge to give you concrete answer but I don't, at least you now have a solid direction. @Tim can you ping Nick or someone else with proper knowledge to take a look on this weird behavior?

Comment: @Ben Okay, wow, that is incredibly weird :) I don't know how much we can help you figure out how to fix this, but I'm passing it along.

Comment: @timpost thanks for you help on the matter and not letting it go unanswered

Comment: @Ben Do you have any more detail to add other then they just get locked out? Any message? Any ... well .. _anything_ that might indicate what's going on? Are they logged in when this happens, or does it happen when they log in? If you can update your post a bit, I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: @timpost I cannot see why this is happening. In ActiveDirectory its just coming up saying the users account has been locked out due to failed logins. This only seems to happen when the users logging/out of stackoverflow or submitting posts or comments. I have watched looked at the network log when the user gets locked out and i cant see anything different in it to if we disable the cookies and the user doesn't get locked out.

Comment: @Ben I'm scratching my head. That's just ... very strange. I'm going to research something, might have a clue.

Comment: @timpost we are still having the lockout issues just not as frequent now. do you have any other ideas what it could be ?

Comment: @timpost it seems the problem was that stack overflow does this request wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com 6 times when loading the page and our webproxy (Sophos UTM) doesnt support WSS. Each WSS request tries to authenticate with our AD and fails.

Answer (score 1):

In users browser i disabled the third party cookies, this stops users accounts getting locked out im not sure of the consequences on other websites due to cookies been blocked.

Comment: Third party cookies are only used during the authentication process (our global auth domain is stackauth.com) - did you try explicitly allowing them from there? Also, did this happen _only_ when trying to login, or just any kind of activity at all?